# Qt - execution of simple loop is slowing down gradually

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtimer

I have loop inside my main window code, that is simply changing the colour of some text-boxes on screen.
It is simply `for(int i=0; i<200; i++)`, but I'd like to make every colour change ***visible to the user***, so inside the loop I've tried to add sth like a *10ms pause*, so every execution is visible on screen.

I used this:

```
      QTimer t;
      t.start(10);
      QEventLoop loop;
      connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
      loop.exec();
```

The problem is, that I'd like to have this *10ms pace* constantly, so the whole operation will take about ~2 seconds. Unfortunately, **it slows down gradually, so hard, that the last ~20 executions takes even about 1 second each**

It looks rather decently when i<20~50, adding more makes it significantly slowing...

I thought about my *not-really-brand-new* PC, but **it is really simple operation** to be done, so I don't really think it is because of my slow pc.
I'm assume my approach is wrong

---

PS. During the execution, `ram usage` for my app is about **~21MB**, and `cpu` about **20-30%**

Comment: I'd go with a QTimer with about 150ms should do the trick. Or just divide the amount the whole color change should be by 200 and you'll have your time for each rgb value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good way to achieve something. `QTimer` is enough to this task. For example:

```
 QTimer *t = new QTimer;//without loops and sleeping
 connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(someSlot()));
 t->start(10);
```

Create `someSlot` and in this slot change color and do other tasks. To stop timer after 2 seconds, you can use counter instead of using system time.

```
void MainWindow::someSlot()
{
    //do something
}
```

Also consider that `10 ms` is very very fast, human eyes not able to catch so fast changing. Try to use longer value.